# Correct way to do find a pattern and replace with a link in a Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My goal is to find something like 'b1234' in a paragraph and replace it with:

```
<a href=http://bugtracker.com/bug/1234>b1234</a>
```

I made this using plain ruby:

```
"I fixed b1234 today".gsub(/(b([0-9]+))/i, '<a href=http://bugtracker.com/bug/\2>\1</a>')
```

It outputs:

```
=> "I fixed <a href=http://bugtracker.com/bug/1234>b1234</a> today"
```

I have the following in my rails view:

```
<%= post.content %>
```

Note: I don't store the HTML link code in my DB when posts are created.

If I do:

```
<%= post.content.gsub(...) %>
```

I get escaped html in the output file:

```
&lt;a href= ... instead of <a href= ...
```

...And **I want that behavior**, I don't want users posting HTML (iframes would be scary!).

*But*, how I can I still get the find and replace functionality I want without sacrificing security? Maybe a Javascript approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double up the equals signs. `<%== post.content.gsub(...) %>`. If users are also potentially writing HTML in this content, then you'll need to [Sanitize](http://wonko.com/post/sanitize) it, so that only specified HTML tags are permitted, for example.

EDIT | Actually, provided the search string you are replacing does not contain HTML special characters, you can just escape the string, *then* do the gsub:

```
<%== h(post.content).gsub(...) %>
```

Comment: You should probably extract this code into a helper function to make it easier to test, reuse and understand.